# sscanf is not declared in this scope - Eclipse, C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, svn

I have a C++ application which code was in an SVN directory. I am trying to open it as a project in the Eclipse editor as I am new to Linux and C++ development and the basic VI editor is just bonkers for me. When I am trying to build the code in the Eclipse editor I am getting an error saying:

**"sscanf is not declared in this scope"**

This piece of code builds and runs fine when I run the make commands on the terminal. Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to #include <stdio.h>.

Comment: Your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Add `#include <cstdio>`

and use `std::sscanf`.